# Colour change video in Firefox with VideoJS

Tags: firefox, colors, video.js

I noticed that all the video's I play in VideoJS player (v4.4.0), in combination with FireFox (v27.0.1) have a yellowish haze over them. For instance, white (255,255,255) shows as 235,235,233. Any body know why this is? And better, how to prevent it? The colour changing doesn't appear in other browsers.

Greetings, Ludo.